# Find a function that maximizes $\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{[f_{i}'(\theta)]^{2}}{f_{i}(\theta)}$

Tags: functions, optimization, polar-coordinates

I'm modeling a physical system and I've ended up with a term (sum of ratios of square of polar function's derivative to the original function) I would like to maximize in order to optimize the performance of the system:

$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{[f_{i}'(\theta)]^{2}}{f_{i}(\theta)}$

where the polar functions $f(\theta)$ model a physical phenomenon which makes them necessarily belong to the class of functions $0 \lt f(\theta) \le 1 $. Since the sum is always positive, a simpler problem to start with would be to maximize each term - but even with that, I don't even know where to begin (I'm an engineer, not a mathematician). I do have further restrictions on the function including some parameterizations if it helps, but I am also curious if there's a general approach that could be used.

Comment: Maybe start by exploring $f’ = a\sqrt{f}$.

Comment: (And your answer will end up depending a whole lot on the constraints.)

Comment: Thanks for that @Aruralreader, I hadn't considered that class of functions. It is very different from a few parameterizations of the model function I have (which are mostly elaborate versions of the form $1-\alpha sin^{n}(\theta)$, $1-\alpha cos^{n}(\theta)$ or similar with a periodic trig function which makes the derivative continuous). But I was interested in a general approach - it may be that I can find an approximation of the form you mentioned for one of the model functions I have.

Comment: In such generality the question is unanswerable. If you want some meaningful input, just post the exact function, tell the domain you want to optimize it on, and clarify if you want an analytic solution or just an algorithm that would produce the answer quickly for some specified range of parameters. Then I promise to think of it for a while.